# React this.props.children with Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic form that I am working on and I was hoping to create a `<Form>` wrapper component.  If all of my form fields(react components) had a function that lived on them called `getValue()` which gave back the values for that component.  I could then grab all my dynamic values in 1 iteration.

```
for(let i = 0; i <  this.props.children.length; i++){

        result.push(this.props.children[i].getValue());

}
```

The problem i am faced with is. For some reason there is no reference to the components functions on the child object. So `getValue` is not defined.

Why is this? Is there a way to be able to dynamically iterate through components and reference there properties/functions in the same manor as `ref's`?

Am I forced to iterate using refs?

jsx proof of concept:

```
     return (  
       <Form ref="form">
        <AdminSeo
            home={true}
            disableRedirect={true}
            disableCanonical={true}
        />

        </Form>
);
```

This would cause this.props.children to be equal to  `[Object]`;

AdminSEO has a property called getValue();

```
   getValue = () => {


    return {...this.state};
  }
```

Comment: If you can see this.props.children outside the for loop then its a binding problem. In that case try `var self = this;for(let i = 0; i <  this.props.children.length; i++){

        result.push(self.props.children[i].getValue());

}`

Comment: I think props.children is the react component reference. It is not referencing to class itself, so no methods are available.